# How to create word2vec for phrases and then calculate cosine similarity

Tags: python, word2vec, data-analysis, cosine-distance

I just started using word2vec and have no idea how to create vectors (using word2vec) of two lists, each containing set of words and phrases and then how to calculate the cosine similarity between these 2 lists.

For example:

```
list1 =['blogs', 'vmware', 'server', 'virtual', 'oracle update', 'virtualization', 'application','infrastructure', 'management']
list2 = ['microsoft visual studio','desktop virtualization',
'microsoft exchange server','cloud computing','windows server 2008']
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply word2vec on multiple words. You should use something like [doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html), which gives a vector for each phrase:

```
phrase = model.infer_vector(['microsoft', 'visual', 'studio'])
```

You can also average or sum the vectors of words (from word2vec) in each phrase, e.g.

```
phrase = w2v('microsoft') + w2v('visual') + w2v('studio')
```

This way, a phrase vector would be the same length as a word vector for comparison. But still, methods like doc2vec are better than a simple average or sum. Finally, you could proceed to compare each word in the first list to every phrase in the second list, and find the closest phrase.

Note that a phrase like "cloud computing" has a completely different meaning than the word "cloud". Therefore, these phrases, specially if frequent, better to be treated as a *single* word, e.g.

```
phrase = w2v('cloud_computing')
```

Extra directions:

1. Here is [an answer by Astariul on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50470359/5341713) that uses a function from word2vec package to calculate similarity between two sets of words.
2. Take a look at [fastText](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html) that works better when there is a lot of misspelled, or out-of-vocabulary words.

Comment: @ Esmailian i want to find the most similar phase in list2 with all words in list1? i can't do this with word2vec?

Comment: you  are saying i cant use word2vec for phrases?

Comment: @user3778289 If it is considered as a single unique word yes, but composition of words no, unless you use average and sum which I put into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Vector representation of phrases (called term-vectors) are used in projects like search results optimization and question answering.

A textbook example is "Chinese river" ~ {"Yangtze_River","Qiantang_River"}  (https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)

Above example identifies phrases based on Nouns mentioned in Freebase DB. There are alternatives such as :

1. Identify all nouns and other phrases based on POS tagging
2. Identify all bi-grams, tri-grams

Filter the list above based on usage (E.g.: only retain terms that have been used at least 500 times in large corpus such as Wikipedia).

Once terms have been identified, Word Vector algo will work as it is :

1. Train word vector model
2. Concat phrases into single tokens and retrain the model
3. Merge these 2 models

Following patent from Google has more details

https://patents.google.com/patent/CN106776713A/en

Other papers that have examples of domains where term vectors have been evaluated / used :

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1801/1801.01884.pdf

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lbing/pub/KBS2018_bing.pdf

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046417302769

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1532046417302769

http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d5/teaching/ws15_16/irdm/slides/irdm2015-ch13-part2-handout.pdf